# MongoDB geting an empty array from an aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation

So I created this controller to get me the sum of all the orders `totalPrice` made by months

```
const getMonthlyOrderTotal = async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const year = req.params.year;
      const aggregatePipeline = [
        {
          $match: {
            createdAt: {
              $gte: new Date(`${year}-01-01T00:00:00.000`),
              $lt: new Date(`${year}-12-31T23:59:59.999`)
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: {
              $month: "$createdAt"
            },
            total: {
              $sum: "$totalPrice"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            _id: 1
          }
        }
      ];
      const orderTotals = await Order.aggregate(aggregatePipeline);
      res.json(orderTotals);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
    }
  };
```

this is the orderModel I am using

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const orderSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: "User",
    },
    client: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: "Client",
    },
    orderItems: [
      {
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        qty: { type: Number, required: true },
        image: { type: String },
        price: { type: Number, required: true },
        product: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          required: true,
          ref: "Product",
        },
      },
    ],
    totalPrice: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      default: 0.0,
    },
    taxPrice: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      default: 0.0,
    },
    isPaid: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      default: false,
    },
    paidAt: {
      type: Date,
    },
    isDelivered: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      default: false,
    },
    deliveredAt: {
      type: Date,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const Order = mongoose.model("Order", orderSchema);

export default Order;
```

and when I try to test this API in postman `"http://localhost:5001/orders/orderstotal/2022"` I always get an empty array even though there is stored data in mongoDB orders Collection

[image: this is how the data looks like in the dataBase]

[image]

Comment: Can you post some sample data? Have you tested your aggregation pipeline using e.g. MongoDB Compas or mongosh? Basic test worked at my end - so pipeline looks good. Is it ensured that the value for `year` is set correct? When the value is empty er something weird the query will also return an empty array.

Comment: @ChristianUnnerstall I just added a picture of how the data looks like in the database , and honestly I have no idea how to test the aggregation pipline in Mongodb Compas

Comment: isn't it because of a type mismatch ? your `createdAt` field is autogenerated by mongoose and includes both a date and a type. Try using this filter : ```{$match: {createdAt: {$gte: new Date(`${year}-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`),$lt: new Date(`${year}-12-31T23:59:59.999Z`)}}}
```

Comment: @rrrrr yeas I tried that before and it did not work still getting an empty array

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/I7lZ43Osp3- this example seems to be working just fine

Comment: @rrrrr can you check the question I Just trie your suggestion in mongoDb in the collection aggregation in it still give me no documents

Comment: Can you do `console.log(req.params.year)` in your `getMonthlyOrderTotal` function and add the result to your question?

Comment: I just find out that it sould be "req.params.id"